# Is there a way to arbitrarily create SymPy variables with the symbols method?

Tags: python, sympy

I am creating an equation solver where the user will select what equation they want, and then will input integers for the given variables in the equation, while leaving one of them blank which will be the unknown variable. Sympy will then solve for the unknown. But first I need to be able to create Sympy variables arbitrarily based on the equation.

Say the equation is:

```
x+y=z
```

I know you can do the following to create the variables:

```
x,y,z = symbols('x y z')
```

Is there any way I can arbitrarily do this or do I have to hard code it as above?

Comment: What does "arbitrarily" mean?

Comment: Maybe `parse_expr` does what you want

Comment: At least scan the `sympy` docs, including the `gotchas`.  For example the `=` will require special handling.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin meaning for every equation I will have different variables and therefore will want to create new sympy variables for every equation